# Ruby Build RPM with Custom Prefix

Tags: ruby, rpm

I'm trying to build an RPM of Ruby 2.3.3 with a custom prefix. I can build it stock on the same system without any errors but when I specify a prefix it fails to compile.

I changed only the configure statement in the stock ruby 2.3.3 spec file:

```
%configure \
  --enable-shared \
  --disable-rpath \
  --without-X11 \
  --without-tk \
  --prefix=/opt/custom/ruby-2.3.3
```

The build fails with no error messages (that I can see) dumping ALL of the files in the source package and no errors before it fails.

**How can I compile Ruby in an RPM that will install in a custom path?**

Comment: please share your spec file if possible. `ruby` spec is rather complicated to know exactly what's going on !

Comment: Spec file is not necessary to be shared for this situation, but the relevant output absolutely is.